# How to "Feature" Products in Luma Theme - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, featured-product, luma-theme

Is there a way to easily feature and have certain products appear on the home page of the out-of-the-box luma theme in magento 2?

Or is that totally a custom built thing?

Comment: This was help full to me. http://inchoo.net/magento-2/featured-products-in-magento-2-with-catalog-products-list-widget/ Shown with working example .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could add a products_list widget to the homepage. In the widget you can define conditions which products are shown (for example products of a specific category)

To do this, you cann add a new widget instance of the Products List widget under Content -> Widgets.

When creating a new Widget, you first have to choose the Widget type and the theme where you want it to be inserted.

In the next step you can define the widget instance and its options. To show it on the homepage you have to add a new layout update with specific page -> Home Page and then choose a container, for example main content top.

After clearing the cache it should show on the homepage

Comment: Excellent. Thank you @DavidVerholen. I'll try that and post back.

Comment: the widget itself is pretty cool compared to the m1 version. we used it today to create a really small module that adds a product slider template to the widget

Comment: Awesome...my step step was to get a rotating image slider going. I'll look into it right away. Thank you @DavidVerholen!

Comment: the type should be Products List (or Catalog Products List or sth)

Comment: I got the "Featured Products" working @DavidVerholen. Although I am not sure how or where the certain list of products came from that populated right away. And, secondly, did you install an external/3rd party slider ? If so how did you do that? (I've used Pretty Photo in the past on my static websites)

Comment: the products shown in the widget can be defined in the condition parameter (if tht's what your asking for). We added a new Template to the widget in a module, which adds the slider functionality. Since more people might want to know how to do this (since widgets are barely covered in the devdocs) it would be nice if you could create a new question for this. Unfortunately I don't know a 3rd party module that can do this atm. You have to have some basic knowledge on how to create a magento2 extension for this